# In Python trying to get this code to throw the error when a duplicate is detected

Tags: python, error-handling, properties

I am learning the @property decorator and I am attempting to use them in a meaningless program and is as follows:

```
class DupError(Exception):
    pass

class Test:
    list_test = []

    def __init__(self, attribute):
        try:
            self._attribute = attribute
            
        except DupError as e:
            msg = ' '.join(e.args)
            message = f'{e.__class__.__name__}: {msg}'
            print(message)
        Test.list_test.append(self)


    @property
    def attribute(self):
        return self._attribute

    @attribute.setter
    def attribute(self, x):
        for value in Test.list_test:
            if value.attribute == x:
                raise DupError('Caught an error!')
        self._attribute = x

t1 = Test('g')
t2 = Test('h')
# trying to throw error
t3 = Test('g')
```

As you can see I am trying to get the program to throw the DupError when the attributes match. For some reason it doesn't work. The DupError needs to be raised in the attribute setter and the try except block needs to be in the init constructor. Anyone know what I am doing wrong. corrections and an explanation are welcome

I was able to get it to work as follows:

```
class DupError(Exception):
    pass

class Test:
    list_test = []

    def __init__(self, attribute):
        try:
            self._attribute = attribute
            self.attribute = attribute
            
        except DupError as e:
            msg = ' '.join(e.args)
            message = f'{e.__class__.__name__}: {msg}'
            print(message)
        Test.list_test.append(self)


    @property
    def attribute(self):
        return self._attribute

    @attribute.setter
    def attribute(self, x):
        for value in Test.list_test:
            if value.attribute == x:
                raise DupError('Caught an error!')
        self._attribute = x

t1 = Test('g')
t2 = Test('h')
# trying to throw error
t3 = Test('g')
```

as you can see I added the line self.attribute = attribute however I think that just kind of bypasses the whole _attribute thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've defined a property you should no longer access the underlying attribute (`_attribute` in your case) directly anywhere else, including the `__init__` method, so the initialization of `_attribute` should be done through the setter method of `attribute` so it can be validated as well:

```
def __init__(self, attribute):
    try:
        self.attribute = attribute
    except DupError as e:
        ...
```

Comment: This is not, at all, what the problem is. The problem is not currently solvable because the MRE doesn't even work but, even if it did, this is not the issue. If we change the MRE to not be living in 2 different worlds, where you put in a str and it magically becomes `self.user_name` it works fine, regardless of `_attribute`

Comment: To be clear, I'm not saying you are wrong. I'm just saying this isn't what is stopping it from working. As proof, take the second example and only change `user_name` to `attribute`.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy The OP asks a very specific question about the use of the `attribute` property, and it is readily apparent that he isn't using the property properly. The question has nothing to do with the `user_name` attribute, which may be what's leftover from the OP's effort to minimize the sample code, which as it is is not executable but does not matter since it is already enough to show what the OP asks about.

Comment: I understand that, but the erroneous `_attribute` assignment is not killing the code. They can do what you say and whatever problem they are having with their real code will persist. The question, as is, is not solvable.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy The fact that the OP says "I was able to get it to work as follows:" tells me that he/she has the rest of the code done properly already, but the sample code doesn't work simply because of his/her edits for minimization, so I wouldn't worry about what he/she doesn't ask about for him/her.

Comment: Apparently I missed the "got it to work" part. I apologize for wasting your time.